# "Double vision" with HTML5mode, Angular with ui router and Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, express, angular-ui-router

I am an absolute noob, so bear with me. I am developing an app with angular and express. I am using ui.router for the angular routing and express to serve the pages.

I've used the following lines to enable html5 mode, which has successfully removed the pound sign (#) from the urls, however when hitting f5, only the view gets loaded, and not the index which should wrap the view.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
```

I tried adding the following lines as suggested online, but now the ui router is loading the index page itself in the view (looks like 2 layers of an infinity mirror, if that makes sense).

```
router.all("/*", function(req, res) {
    res.render("index", { user : req.user });
});
```

I've seen res.sendfile used in examples, but I haven't had any success with that, either.

How can I use Angular's ui router, and express in html5mode without breaking my page? I can gladly give more code if needed.

Edit: more info!

Express serves the index page when '/' is requested.
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index', { user : req.user });
    });

The index page simply contains
    ""
which in turn shows the contents of which view I want to show.

**EDIT:** I have uploaded my project to github. https://github.com/shhtephe/SurfacingSolutions
The files I think you'll most need to see are **routes/index.js** and **views/index.ejs**

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of the result?
Are view templates embedded or loaded from URL?  The long shot is that as router.all /* responds to ANY HTTP call You return the same page again for externally loaded templates.

Comment: [This](http://imgur.com/IaMCD01) is with the express route shown above and [this](http://imgur.com/u24pUPu) is with the code commented out.

The Template IS externally loaded (I have a folder /views/partials which contains the views).

Comment: I'm guessing your angular SPA is from '/'?  In which case you need to get your express app to serve the index page for '/' AND any other SPA pages that angular is doing (e.g. /home, /user, /whatever) BUT not for any api calls that you angular app makes to get data (e.g. /api/user/5, etc.).  Does that make sense?

Comment: I keep forgetting that return submits a comment. Sorry. I'll edit my question to add more info. When '/' is requested, express serves the index page, which contains the ui-view tags.

Comment: @ajkavanagh, I think it makes sense, but I'm much more of a hands on/exmaples I can see guy :(

Comment: So I've still not been able to fix this issue. @ajkavanagh, I'm actually using http post actions to get express to pull data from mongo. Angular aside from sending a post to express, angular doesn't do anything to grab the data. I feel like I should probably be using angular for everything related to  the spa page, and only have express server the index page. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Having looked at your code, it looks like you're doing a hybrid of an SPA and a regular multi-page, server-side rendered, app?  i.e. you're using express to render pages (with values) and serving that to angular as partials.  The problem is that angular will only fetch the HTML ONCE, and then cache it.  I'll stare at your code some more and then try an write an 'answer' that helps.